# Check which user is currently using the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two types of users for my app,Staff and Student. I am using firebase auth to authenticate these users. They have separate login pages and their data are stored in different Childs of the database. If the user is a student she shall not be able to use some features of the app that are specific to the Staff. Is there any way to check which user is currently logged in so that I can manipulate the features of my app accordingly?
Ps: I am using email and password login

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI7n6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the user type in the database.

Database structure :

```
root
 |
 +-- users
 |     |
 |     +-- $userId
 |           |
 |           +-- type : $type (staff or student)
```

Set the user type :

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("type").setValue(userType);
```

(userType will be **staff** or **student**)

You can retrieve the current user id with :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    // User is signed 
    String userId = user.getUid();
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

Get the user type :

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("type").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String userType = snapshot.getValue();
    }
}
```

[Firebase Realtime Database documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: Thank u for replying.Your Idea seems perfect but the problem is that the child name is itself the user type and the user_id is saved inside that child.You can check my database structure above. Is there any way to check that the user_id exists in which child?